# How to move an image

Tags: xcode

I am creating an app where bombs come into the screen and blow up this thing that you have to move. How do I make these bombs fly into the screen and move in random directions automatically ? Kind of like fruit ninja where the fruits fly out at you. How do I code that ? What do I need to do ? Please also provide some code. Thank you !

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - are you developing for Mac OS X ? iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, called Bomb or something and it needs to have an instance variable and property of CGRect on iOS or NSRect on Mac OS.

Then create a method that can draw the bomb on the screen, like - drawOnScreen or just - draw which knows how to draw the object. Which would contain code like [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bomb1"] drawInRect:self.frame]

Then in your game loop you simple change the coordinates of the frame of such a bomb object to make it move, of course you will need to do that before calling the draw method as it would draw the previous frame then..

There also is another way of adding a subview to the gameview every time you need a new bomb. However a view has more overhead than using the object I described above and would most likely cause your game to run slow if you have like 50/60+ ( wild guess ) bombs.

For controls on the screen like a pause button I would definitely use a view and add it as a subview.

Comment: unfortunately i am new to this stuff... can u please provide code